# setSearchParams not deleting query param

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have 4 buttons that I'm rendering on my UI

```
const categories = ['Thing1', 'Thing2', 'Thing3', 'Thing4'];

// ...
const [filters, setFilters] = useState<string[]>([]);

const handleCategoryClick = useCallback((category: string) => {
  const updatedFilters = [...filters];

  // Deleting an existing filter
  // Find the index of the existing filter and remove it
  const index = updatedFilters.indexOf(value);
  if (index > -1) {
    updatedFilters.splice(index, 1);
    setFilters(updatedFilters);
    return;
  }

  // Adding a filter
  updatedFilters.push(value);

  setFilters(updatedFilters)
  
}, [filters);

return (
  <Container>
    {categories.map(category => (
      <div onClick={() => handleCategoryClick(category)}>{category}</div>
    )}
  </Container>
);
```

This works well, but now I want to add query params with `react-router` and `useSearchParams`.

I am able to add another `useEffect` and add/remove params to my URL with `useSearchParams`, however I want to *remove* the query param when there are no categories selected, **which is not working**:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!!filters.length) {
    setSearchParams({
      categories: filters.map((category) => category.toLowerCase()).join(','),
    });
  } else if (!filters.length) {
    if (searchParams.has('categories')) {
      console.log('search param exists');
      searchParams.delete('categories');
    }
  }
}, [filters]);
```

`searchParams.delete('categories')` isn't exactly working and I'm not sure why -- my `console.log` is logging *something*, but deleting it doesn't work. As a result, I'm left with a url that looks like `localhost:3000/classes?categories=Thing1` even if there's no existing filters (empty arr).

Am I doing something wrong with trying to delete the param? Should I fall back to `URLSearchParam`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`searchParams` is just the `URLSearchParams` object, mutating it in code only mutates the object and doesn't do anything to the current URL. For this you must call `setSearchParams` again and pass the updated `searchParams` object to effect a navigation change with the new queryString value.

[useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params)

> ### Note:
>
> The `setSearchParams` function works like `navigate`, but only for the
> [search portion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search) of the URL. Also note that the second arg to
> `setSearchParams` is the same type as the second arg to `navigate`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!!filters.length) {
    setSearchParams({
      categories: filters.map((category) => category.toLowerCase()).join(','),
    });
  } else {
    if (searchParams.has('categories')) {
      console.log('search param exists');

      searchParams.delete('categories');
      setSearchParams(searchParams);
    }
  }
}, [filters, searchParams]);
```

There is also a callback updater syntax (*similar how `React.useState` works*) that is passed the current `URLSearchParams` value.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!!filters.length) {
    setSearchParams({
      categories: filters.map((category) => category.toLowerCase()).join(','),
    });
  } else {
    setSearchParams(searchParams => {
      if (searchParams.has('categories')) {
        console.log('search param exists');
        searchParams.delete('categories');
      }
      return searchParams;
    });
  }
}, [filters]);
```